# --skip-ssl-validation option not working with uaac in cloud foundry

Tags: ssl, cloud-foundry, cloudfoundry-uaa

I have created an instance of the uaac service in cloud foundry and have associated it with one of my application. Now, when I try to target my CLI to the uaac instance I get the following error,

```
$ uaac target <uaac URL> 
failed to access <uaac URL>: Invalid SSL Cert for <uaac URL>/login. Use '--skip-ssl-validation' to continue with an insecure target
```

I have added the option as per the message,

```
 $ uaac target <uaac URL> --skip-ssl-validation
```

But again I get the same error,

```
failed to access <uaac URL>: Invalid SSL Cert for <uaac URL>/login. Use '--skip-ssl-validation' to continue with an insecure target
```

I am not sure why the option is not considered and I get the same error again even after mentioning the option.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this is an [known issue](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cf-uaac/issues/37) as of this writing:

On the github comments someone suggests a workaround via a setting in the config file (`~/.uaac.yml` by default):

```
https://127.0.0.1:8580:
  skip_ssl_validation: true
  ca_cert:
```

for a local uaa at 8580.

This only worked for me with the `uaac target` command, but apparently [not](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cf-uaac/issues/41) for the `uaac token` command

Answer (score 1):

My solution was to use the http prefix before my uaa Ip

```
uaac target http://10.81.4.236:8080
```